# Generate slightly different APKs from the same code

Tags: android, android-studio, android-productflavors, amazon-appstore

I developed a small game that uses `Parse` and `push notifications` (GCM, `Google Cloud Messaging`). However when I try to upload my app to the Amazon Store, they say that it will be not published in certain devices because it’s using GCM.

So, the solution is easy, just remove `notifications`.
The problem I have is that I will like to automate the apk generation as much as I can.
Under iOS (I'm iOS developer, new to Android), I just create 2 targets and using a DEFINE I can modify code according to the target.
I would like to have something similar, so I use another `manifest` in the amazon version, and of course I remove the push code.

How can I do that when using `Android Studio`?
I suspect I have to use gradle or maybe the concept of module, because when creating a `signed apk` in `Android Studio` I have to select `“app” module`.

Do you have any idea, suggestion or link? Thanks.

Comment: Single application should contain single Manifest.

Comment: you can't have two manifests for sure. you can have two app modules i guess but i will suggest to have two separate VCS branches instead of duplicating whole code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can accomplish this using product flavors. Each product flavor can have its own AndroidManifest, and each flavor's manifest will get merged with the main applications manifest at compile time. See the [build variants](https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants) section of the documentation.

As an example, you can define the following product flavors

```
productFlavors {
    amazon
    googleplay
}
```

Then you can set up the following manifest files

```
src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
src/amazon/AndroidManifest.xml
src/googleplay/AndroidManifest.xml <-- put GCM permissions here
```

You can also put all of your Google Play Services code and dependencies into your googleplay flavor, for example:

```
dependencies {
    googleplayCompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know build variants. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I do that when using Android Studio?

This is a job for [product flavors](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants). Create a `google` flavor and an `amazon` flavor. Then:

- Use `googleCompile`, instead of `compile`, for your Play Services SDK dependencies.
- Have the Play Services metadata only in your `google` flavor's edition of the manifest.
- Have the code that depends upon the Play Services SDK be in the `google` flavor's sourceset. Note that you may need to abstract some hooks to that code out to a `NotificationStrategy` class that you implement in each flavor, where the `google` one does the Play Services work and the `amazon` flavor does something else (or nothing). Your code in `main` can then reference `NotificationStrategy` and get the right implementation for each flavor.